# Menu in the toolbar changes or disappears

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-menu

The structure of my app , an Activity with fragments that use navigationcomponent.
In the toolbar of my HomeFragment there is a toolbar with a search icon as a menu. This clicked icon leads to the search activity.
[HomeFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnw6r.png)

Browsing in my app and changing fragment up to the ProfileFragment, I have the opportunity to view my lists and clicking on one of these opens another fragment to show the contents of that list
[ProfileFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXsSM.png), [ShowListContent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpLES.png).

**Now here's the magic**

If I click on the toolbar icon to change the description of my list everything is perfect and we are delighted but ...

[New HomeFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmHOi.png)

If I go back to the HomeFragment, the icon in the toolbar is no longer the same and I cannot go to the SearchActivity.

*What can I do to avoid this problem?*

**Code time**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{

  @Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

 }
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, 
    false);

    initToolbar(view);

    //other code

    return view;
 }
  private void initToolbar(View view) {
    Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main_toolbar);

 }
  @Override
  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NotNull Menu menu, @NotNull MenuInflater 
    inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main_toolbar, menu);

 }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.menu_search) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SearchActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
    return true;
 }
}
```

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#141a32"
tools:context=".fragments.HomeFragment">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        style="@style/toolbar"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main_toolbar"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout">

    //other code

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**ShowContentListFragment**

```
public class ShowContentListFragment extends Fragment{

  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragments_layout_lists, container, false);
    
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    
    getDataFromSafeArgs();

    initWidgets(view);

    initToolbar();

    return view;
 }
  private void initToolbar() {
    toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_friend_list_back_button);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_profile_edit_list);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> {
        
    Navigation.findNavController(getView())
     .navigate(R.id.action_showContentListFragment_to_profileFragmentOriginal);
        movies_into_list.clear();
        getAndPostMovieIntoLIstModel.clearPersonalList();
    });
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_edit) {
            dialogModifyDescription();
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }

    });

 }
  @Override
  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_profile_edit_list, menu);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

 }
}
```

**fragment_showListContent.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/big_stone"
tools:context=".fragments.MyListsFragment">

<include
    layout="@layout/layout_toolbar"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

//other code

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have 1 toolbar and maybe 1 menu and instead disable/enable icons using `menu.findItem(R.id.menu_edit).setVisible(true/false);`

Maybe you could try calling `requireActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu()` as well.

Comment: This fragement home is one of the three fragments (home, saved and profile) which can be accessed via a bottom bar. From what I understand the onCreateView is no longer called after the first time, consequently setHasOptionMenu present in the onCreateView is no longer called